# MongoDb how to fetch rows with missing property

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

When finding non deleted rows, I use the following filer:

```
DBCursor myCursor=collection.find(new BasicDBObject("companyId",companyId)
.append("isDeleted",Boolean.FALSE))
```

The issue is that some records doesn't have the "isDeleted" column, so (I assume) that this is the reason they don't appear in the list

How to include both records with isDeleted= false

and records where the isDeleted property is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want the [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator. But probably coupled with the [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator to cover both possible values, where set or does not exist at all:

```
   BasicDBList myOr = new BasicDBList();
   myOr.add(new BasicDBObject("isDeleted", false));
   myOr.add(new BasicDBObject("isDeleted", new BasicDBObject("$exists", false)));


   DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("companyId",1)
       .append("$or", myOr);

   DBCursor myCursor = collection.find(query);
```

The "$exists" basically asks whether the specified field "exists or not" depending on the `true|false` value you specify as an argument.

Please note that `$exists` does not interrogate an index. Your best option is to make sure each document actually has the field present with a value you can query on.